# RabbitMQBundle does not acknowledge message when producing message from consumer

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, message-queue

**How to acknowledge the message and produce a new message at the same time?**

When I start my consumer from the command line, the messages will stay in the original queue. But new ones will be created in the new queue, in an infinite loop. Because it keeps consuming the messages that are not being acknowledged.

Even though TRUE is returned in the execute() function of the consumer. Which should acknowledge it, like it says in the documentation.

I am producing messages from a callback inside a consumer. This producer is injected using the standard Symfony DI.

If I remove the method that publishes the new message, the messages are acknowledged just fine...

services.yml

```
services:
  my_importlog_repository:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments: [AppBundle\Entity\MyImportlogEntity]
  my_distributor:
    class: AppBundle\DistributorImport\MyDistributor
    arguments: [@my_importlog_repository,@logger,@old_sound_rabbit_mq.my_download_producer, %my_config%]
  my_download:
    class: AppBundle\Consumer\MyDownloadConsumer
    arguments: [@logger,@old_sound_rabbit_mq.my_extract_producer,@my_distributor,%my_config%]
  my_extract:
    class: AppBundle\Consumer\MyExtractConsumer
    arguments: [@logger,@old_sound_rabbit_mq.my_convert_producer,@my_distributor,%my_config%]
```

config.yml

```
# rabbitmq
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
  connections:
    default:
      host:     '192.168.99.100'
      port:     5672
      user:     'guest'
      password: 'guest'
      vhost:    '/'
      lazy:     false
      connection_timeout: 60
      read_write_timeout: 60

      # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+ and PHP5.4+
      keepalive: false

      # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+
      heartbeat: 30
  producers:
    # my producers
    my_download:
      connection:       default
      exchange_options: {name: 'distributor_import', type: direct}
      queue_options:    {name: 'my_download'}
    my_extract:
      connection:       default
      exchange_options: {name: 'distributor_import', type: direct}
      queue_options:    {name: 'my_extract'}
    my_convert:
      connection:       default
      exchange_options: {name: 'distributor_import', type: direct}
      queue_options:    {name: 'my_convert'}
  consumers:
    # my consumers
    my_download:
      connection:       default
      exchange_options: {name: 'distributor_import', type: direct}
      queue_options:    {name: 'my_download'}
      callback:         my_download
      qos_options:      {prefetch_size: 0, prefetch_count: 1, global: false}
      idle_timeout:     60
    my_extract:
      connection:       default
      exchange_options: {name: 'distributor_import', type: direct}
      queue_options:    {name: 'my_extract'}
      callback:         my_extract
      qos_options:      {prefetch_size: 0, prefetch_count: 1, global: false}
      idle_timeout:     60
```

MyDownloadConsumer.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Consumer;

use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ConsumerInterface;

class MyDownloadConsumer implements ConsumerInterface
{
  private $logger;
  private $producer;
  private $distributor;
  private $config;

  public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, \OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Producer $producer, \AppBundle\DistributorImport\MyDistributor $distributor, Array $config)
  {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->producer = $producer;
    $this->distributor = $distributor;
    $this->config = $config;
  }

  public function execute(\PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage $message)
  {
    $data = unserialize($message->body);
    $this->producer->publish(serialize($data));
    return true;
  }
}
```

If I remove

```
$data = unserialize($message->body);
$this->producer->publish(serialize($data));
```

It works like it should...

Comment: if You want to requeue the message just return false in the end ;-)

Comment: @mmmm This is not what I wanted to do. I wanted to send a new message, to the same queue. Or another queue. But the result remained the same. The original message did not get ACKed.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to publish a message from inside my Consumer execute() method, while also acknowledging the current message being consumed. Using the following code.

```
$message->delivery_info['channel']
    ->basic_publish(
        new AMQPMessage (serialize($data)),
        'name_of_my_exchange',
        'key.of.my.routing'
    );
```

Publishing directly on the channel of the message that is being consumed.

Comment: Just commenting here to say that the messages sent using this method are not persistent anymore...